# How to access value of jquery datatable column in order to pass as a parameter to controller

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need help getting the value from "media_type" column of my jquery datatable.

Beginning on line 54, I am passing 3 parameters to my controller (id1, id2, id3) when the DELETE button is pressed. Getting the value for the third parameter (id3) from the column on line 18 called "media_type" is where I am stuck. The value will either contain the value "Image" or "PDF". When I put a breakpoint on my controller action (projects/deleteprojectmedia), the value of id3 on Line 56 is blank or null upon entering the controller action.

My feeble attempt is on line 48 and 49:

```
var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr"); 
var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();**
```

but it just isn't working. On Line 50, I put an alert to see what the value might be and it said it is undefined.

Thank you in advance!

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                      var table = $("#projectmedia").DataTable({
                        ajax: {
                            url: "/projects/getprojectmedia/",
                                        "type": "GET",
                                        "datatype": "json",
                                        data: {
                                            id: "@Model.Projects.Project_Guid"
                                            }},
                                           "columns": [
                                                {
                                                data: "project_media_guid",
                                                    render: function (data) {
                                                    return "<a href='/projectmedia/view/" + data + "'>" + "View" + "</a>";
                                                }
                                            },
                                        { "data": "media_type", "autoWidth": true },                     
                                        { "data": "media_title", "autoWidth": true },
                                        {
                                        "data": "entered_date",
                                            render: function (data) {
                                            if (data != null) {
                                                var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
                                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                                return (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/"
                                                    + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear()
                                                    + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + (date.getHours() < 10 ? ("0" + date.getHours()) : date.getHours())
                                                    + ":" + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? ("0" + date.getMinutes()) : date.getMinutes());
                                            } else {
                                                return "";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                        {
                                        data: "project_media_guid",
                                            render: function (data) {
                                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-projectmedia-guid=" + data + ">Delete</button";
                                        }
                                    },
                                    ]
                                });

                                $("#projectmedia").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
                                    var button = $(this);
                                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this media?", function (result) {
                                        if (result) {
                                            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr"); 
                                            var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
                                            alert(col2);
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: "/projects/deleteprojectmedia/",
                                                data: {
                                                    id: button.attr("data-projectmedia-guid"),
                                                    id2: "@Model.Projects.Project_Guid",
                                                    id3: col2
                                                },
                                                method: "DELETE",
                                                success: function () {
                                                    table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                    });
                </script>
```

Here is the datatable with the value = "Image" of my Media Type column. When I click the Delete button, I am trying to grab the value of "Image" and pass it as a parameter.
[image]

As you can see from my alert, the value I attempted to grab is blank:

[image]

And finally, when I breakpoint in my controller, you can see the parameter is blank.
[image]

Comment: Did you debug the dev console? Any error there? do all rows of table have element which is "projectmedia" (id) ?

Comment: No error in dev console. The value just isn't extracting.

Comment: what about element id "projectmedia" ? Is that repeating?

Comment: I have none defined as id. As you can see from script, I was able to populate id: by using the button.attr and id2: by using the @Model. The third one is displayed in the Media Type column as Image or PDF like this:                              { "data": "media_type", "autoWidth": true },

Comment: Actually id should be unique, if it is repeating more than one time (in rows), you have to use class, if you use id, it will always take the first recod

Comment: Let me put the question this way. How do I format my media_type column so that when I click the delete button, I can extract the value when the delete button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33945/getting-value-of-selected-rows

[image]

The data element assigned to the column is media_type
When the delete button is clicked, I first get the selected row data.
I then extract the value of that column by referencing the column (rowData.media_type) and assigning it to the variable mMediaType. I then associate the value stowed in mMediaType to parameter id3. My controller now receives the value of "Image" or "PDF" in the 3rd parameter of my action in my controller.